# Can't add Business Module or Foundation Module in Smart Client solution. Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, scsf, guidance-automation-tool

I've recently switched from VS 2010 professional to VS 2015 Community and I have encountered a problem with the Smart Client Software Factory 2010. I have downloaded and installed the GAX and Smart Client Software Factory for VS2015. I am able to create a Smart Client application (C#) and I get the usual template projects within the Infrastructure folder (which in turn is placed in the Source folder), Shell, Interface, Library and others. Now the problem I have encountered is that I cannot add Business Modules to the solution. I can't do it through the "New Project" wizard nor through right-clicking on the source folder and picking "Smart Client Software Factory 2010" -> "Add Business Module". The "Smart Client Software Factory 2010" option isn't even in the right-click menu. The only place it is showing up is in the right click menu for the created projects, and the sub-menu only gives the "Create View with presenter" options.

Any ideas what causes this strange behaviour and how I might fix it? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I dug around some more and in guidance navigator I see the "Add Add Fundational(C#) Module" and "Add Add Business Module(C#)" as templates. (Not a typo the word Add appears twice)

[image]

When I click "unfold this template" I get a window with my solution tree:
[image]

but when I then select source (because that is where I want the business module to be created and click accept nothing happens and Visual Studio gives me the following message:

[image]

Something that I forgot to mention in the original message is that I also installed GAT and enabled it in the Guidance Automation Manager.
So any ideas?

Comment: Came back to this again. I tried to generate just a view with presenter, the only thing that seems to work. And it still gave the "This item does not support previewing", but at least it had a desired effect. I was able to generate a view with presenter. I don't think there is any trouble with previous versions of scsf, but it seems that the only version installable on the VS2015 is the scsf2015 which is in beta, so might be that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. This seems to be one of those things that you don't even think of trying out. Apparently in order for scsf to be able to start of its "New Project" wizard (which business module and foundational module are, they are new projects within the solution) you have to run Visual Studio as admin. Once I did that the Guidance Navigator was able to add the mentioned modules to the solution.